# How to change the font of only chapter titles and subsections?

Tags: fonts, titles, fontspec

I'm trying to change the font of my chapter titles and subsections but none of the examples online are working for me. Here is my current code and the typesetting it generates. How do I change the font of the title and subsections? E.g., I want set the title and subsection fonts to Arial to keep the body font as Palatino.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Palatino}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index]
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle,
    citestyle=authortitle
]{biblatex}\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\centering}{\huge\thechapter}{1em}{\Huge #1}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/introduction}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter01}

\theendnotes
\printbibliography

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the `titlesec` package. It explains on page 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the chapter and subsection titles to Arial via the `titlesec` and `fontspec` packages. I've also commented out some code so that the code works on my machine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}%I don't have Palatino.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index]
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle,
    citestyle=authortitle
]{biblatex}\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newfontfamily{\arialfont}{Arial Nova}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
    [display]%
    {%
        \bfseries%
        \centering%
        \arialfont%
    }%
    {\huge\thechapter}%
    {1em}%
    {\Huge #1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    [display]
    {%
        \bfseries%
        \arialfont%
    }
    {\thesubsubsection}
    {}
    {#1}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
%\include{./TeX_files/introduction}
%\include{./TeX_files/chapter01}
\blinddocument

%\theendnotes
%\printbibliography

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @User23456234